# send several headers of cookie , only the last one is sent

Tags: php, cookies, header

```
header('Set-Cookie: test1=test2; path=/');
header('Set-Cookie: meepo=3927; path=/');    
header('Set-Cookie: 1234567=890; path=/');
```

Only the last value is set `1234567=890`, how to set more than one cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the manual for [header()](http://php.net/header) the signature of this function is like

```
void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

The second parameter is `true` be default and it tells you, that previous headers with the same name will be overwritten. Set it to `false`

Comment: thank you very much . Shame on myself. I should read the manual at first.